# Constructor method not accessible on object method on Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is my code

```
export class Test {
   constructor(
    private readonly logger: PinoLogger,
  ) {}

  @Put('test')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: '/uploads',
        filename: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
          cb(null, req.body.filename);
        },
      }),

      fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
          this.logger.info(`Test log`);
        }
      },
    }),
  )
}
```

On this I'm not able access `logger` getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logger')`

Comment: Make `fileFilter` an arrow function.

Comment: @caTS tried its throwing this is undefined